# Values not selected from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, rows, fetch

I have this php

```
<?php       
    require("./connect.php");

    $cust_name=$_POST['name'];
    $cust_addr=$_POST['shippingAddr'];
    $cust_pincode=$_POST['pincode'];
    $buttonid=$_REQUEST['button_id'];

    $query=mysql_query("select * from button where button_id='$buttonid'");
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    //echo "error is ".$numrows;
       if($numrows==1)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        $merchant_id = $row['merchant_id'];
        echo "hi SUCCESS id is ".$buttonid;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<br>EROR NOT inserted id is ".$buttonid;
    } 
?>
```

Im not able to fetch data using

```
$query=mysql_query("select * from button where button_id='$buttonid'");
```

i tried echoing `$numrows` but it returns 0 always.I tried mysql_error ,I didnt got any errors.and tried error_get_last , also no errors.

Im sure the other connect.php for connecting to database and all is working properly.and button_id variable is also populated.But the select statement doesnt seems to work?Any help.

**UPDATE**

I have found that there is white spaces `button_id=' mmrw6FJFfDWBYt2aSO1qm '` in my button_id.Why does that happen.The vairable originally dont have it.How can i remove it?

Comment: Try echoing the `SELECT` statement to make sure it contains what you expect.

Comment: If you're getting no rows, the only possible reason is because there aren't any rows that match `$buttonid`.

Comment: With the info you posted, it is hard to guess the error. Better post your `buttonid` input value and table data screen shot.

Comment: Now ... Now ... See .. your so called `buttonid` is a `varchar`, and every one was thinking, due to the naming convention practices, that it is a number and down voting someone else's answers for suggesting to put back quotes.

Comment: Note that you're using a deprecated connection method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sidenote beforehand you should put LIMIT 1 at the end of your query if you are only expecing one single row to be returned.

However your code seems pretty fine are you sure that button_id is filled properly? Try to use:

```
var_dump($buttonid);
```

Besides you used $buttonid but the name of your element in html seems to be button_id, is this a typing error perhaps?

Additionally try to print your resolved query:

```
echo "select * from button where button_id='$buttonid'";
```

and put the result in phpmyadmin to debug it until it works before using mysql_query, a general useful hint.

Comment: I tried this and I found that there are white spaces before and after button_id  button_id=' mmrw6FJFfDWBYt2aSO1qm ' why does that happen? and how to remove it?

Comment: The most easy way to remove it would be typecasting if you know that the value should be numerical, this brings in safety against sql injection aswell:
echo "select * from button where button_id='" . intval($buttonid) . '";

Answer (score 0):

For integer type filed you need enclose with " '  " quotes , 
try this

```
$query=mysql_query("select * from button where button_id=$buttonid");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you should use quotation marks and php will be able got that.
something like this

If button_id in your database is `int` or `number` You wouldn't retype this.

```
$query=mysql_query("select * from button where button_id=$buttonid");
```

If button_id in your database is `varchar` or `string` use this solution

```
$query=mysql_query("select * from button where button_id='" . $buttonid . "'");
```

It will be better to define query this way.

and php code

```
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$result['columnInDb'];
```

Answer (score 0):

1-

```
$query=mysql_query("select * from button where button_id=$buttonid");
$buttonid  >>> without single because it num
```

2-

```
use $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

instead of `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);`

Answer (score 0):

> I have found that there is white spaces button_id=' mmrw6FJFfDWBYt2aSO1qm ' in my button_id.Why does that happen.The vairable originally dont have it.How can i remove it?

Use [***TRIM***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) function. It removes trailing spaces.

```
$query=mysql_query("select * from button where button_id=trim('$buttonid')");
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all try to debug $buttonid, see if it actually is a variable that includes content

```
print_r($buttonid);
```

If that's true, then change your query to

```
$query=mysql_query("select * from button where button_id='" . $buttonid . "'");
```

Comment: Why would concatenation instead of substitution make a difference?